# How do you add indexes to databases with MigratorDotNet?

Tags: c#, database, migratordotnet

Can someone point me in the right direction for creating indexes when using MigratorDotNet?

I have some tables which need multi column indexes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 0.8, it doesn't look like it's possible.  A [patch for adding multi-columned indexes](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/issues/detail?id=101) was submitted sometime back in 2009, but it hasn't been accepted yet.

The code to do this can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/issues/attachmentText?id=101&aid=1613288934701879019&name=migratordotnet-multicolumnindex.patch&token=3c9602cf02606db25c76bea5506b2404).  I'd post a complete snipped from the patch, but I'm not sure what kind of licensing issues you or anyone else that's reading this answer might face by looking at MPL code.

Comment: If, like most people, you are just using Migrator.Net internally to support your development, there are no licensing issues. If you actually distribute Migrator.Net code, compiled code or even compile with references to Migrator.Net, that's another story.